# Can I return an Interface within an Enum

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, react-typescript

Can I return an Interface within an Enum?

```
const PREFIX: string = 'TEST';

interface DataValidated {
    serial: string;
}

enum DataType {
    Invalid,
    DataValidated
}

class DataValidate {
 
    validate(data: string) : DataType {
        if (data.startsWith(PREFIX)) {
            return DataType.Invalid;
        }

        return DataType.DataValidated = {
            serial: data,
        };
    }
}
```

I am getting the following errors:

- Type '{ serial: string; }' is not assignable to type 'DataType'.(2322)
- Cannot assign to 'DataValidated' because it is a read-only property.(2540)

Comment: I think you're thinking of Java-style `enum` types? That won't work: TypeScript enums are  more like C# `enum` types (i.e. they're just _named constants_). The TypeScript equivalent of Java-style `enum` types is a union type, though you'll also need to define the types in the union as distinct structural-types (unlike in Java where they're nominative types that can be structurally alike).

Comment: No, this is not supported. Enums are collections of exact values.

Comment: @Dai I was thinking of Rust style enums. Not familiar with Java all that much.

Comment: What do you want to achieve with that last `return`? You can't assign a value to an enum member like this.

Comment: In that case, as far as my comment above is concerned, "Java enum" and "Rust enum" are interchangeable.

Comment: @Cuzy I wanted to return an `interface` along with its data when validated. And wanted to return an `enum` `Invalid` when it's not. I could add a `valid` `bool` to my `interface`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enums cannot wrap values in TS. Make your return type a discrimated union :

```
interface DataInvalid {
  type: DataType.Invalid;
}

interface DataValidated {
    serial: string;
    type: DataType.DataValidated;
}
interface Data : DataValidated|DataInvalid

class DataValidate {
 
    validate(data: string) : Data {
        if (data.startsWith(PREFIX)) {
            return {type: DataType.Invalid};
        }

        return = {
            type: DataType.DataValidated
            serial: data,
        };
    }
}
```

That way the compiler will able to infer if there is data, when you're testing for `data.type`